# How to choose specific time in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to choose a range of time from my data, but I can't find the approach to choose a range of time in this code.
How do I fix my code?
Thanks!!!

I saw this code

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'EUROSTOXX': es['SX5E'][es.index > dt.datetime(1999, 1, 1)]})
```

from my textbook. 
The time I want to correct is from (1999, 1, 1) to (2016, 1, 1)

I tried several codes to change the time, for example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'EUROSTOXX': es['SX5E'][dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1)> es.index > dt.datetime(1999, 1, 1)]})
```

but it failed. Is there anyone could save me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice a Pandas Time Series using a logical expression involving dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774055/how-to-slice-a-pandas-time-series-using-a-logical-expression-involving-dates)

Comment: Its always  advisable to provide the minimal code which can ve reproduce in order to get and provide explicit and more feasible answer, Would you be able to show us few line of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should work :

`data = pd.DataFrame({'EUROSTOXX': es['SX5E'][(es.index > datetime(1999, 1, 1)) & (es.index < dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1))]})`

Answer (score 0):

Just an example for illustration to Select Time Range:

**DataFrame Example:**

```
>>> df
                 date
0 2001-01-01 00:00:00
1 2001-01-01 01:00:00
2 2001-01-01 02:00:00
3 2001-01-01 03:00:00
4 2001-01-01 04:00:00
5 2001-01-01 05:00:00
6 2001-01-01 06:00:00
7 2001-01-01 07:00:00
8 2001-01-01 08:00:00
9 2001-01-01 09:00:00
```

**One way you can get it as follows:**

```
>>> df[(df['date'] > '2001-01-01 00:00:00') & (df['date'] <= '2001-01-01 03:00:00')]
                 date
1 2001-01-01 01:00:00
2 2001-01-01 02:00:00
3 2001-01-01 03:00:00
```

**Secondly, setting the `date` column as an Index and then applying `loc` method:**

```
>>> df = df.set_index(df['date'])
>>> df
                                   date
date
2001-01-01 00:00:00 2001-01-01 00:00:00
2001-01-01 01:00:00 2001-01-01 01:00:00
2001-01-01 02:00:00 2001-01-01 02:00:00
2001-01-01 03:00:00 2001-01-01 03:00:00
2001-01-01 04:00:00 2001-01-01 04:00:00
2001-01-01 05:00:00 2001-01-01 05:00:00
2001-01-01 06:00:00 2001-01-01 06:00:00
2001-01-01 07:00:00 2001-01-01 07:00:00
2001-01-01 08:00:00 2001-01-01 08:00:00
2001-01-01 09:00:00 2001-01-01 09:00:00
```

Now using `loc` :

```
>>> df.loc['2001-01-01 00:00:00':'2001-01-01 03:00:00']
                                   date
date
2001-01-01 00:00:00 2001-01-01 00:00:00
2001-01-01 01:00:00 2001-01-01 01:00:00
2001-01-01 02:00:00 2001-01-01 02:00:00
2001-01-01 03:00:00 2001-01-01 03:00:00
```

Hope it will help.